# ASP.NET Core auth error, when using custom Login code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, minimal-apis

I have a simple backend app. I have and endpoint called /notes for fetching notes. I have added `RequireAuthorization()` to it but I can't authorize the users. I have written the login and signup endpoints myself so that they send JWT tokens.

This is where I setup auth:

```cs
void ConfigAuth(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<User>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDBContext>();
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer();
    builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
    builder
        .Services
        .AddAuthorizationBuilder()
        .AddPolicy("admin", policy => policy.RequireRole("admin"))
        .AddDefaultPolicy("user", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser());
}
```

This is the error I get after calling `/notes` route with authorization header:

> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions+CompositeIdentityHandler[7]
> Identity.BearerAndApplication was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotected token failed

This is how I implement login: [Link](https://github.com/OmidNejadabbasi/notit-backend/blob/4c2fab8839564cc090c04c7a0b6f2d9308fc8922/app/endpoints/AuthEndpoints.cs#L18)

Here is the link to my code in github: https://github.com/OmidNejadabbasi/notit-backend

Comment: Based on your shared code, I can't see that you have inject app user within your DI, according to your error it indicates that you are missing auth handler Injection.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron If you mean adding them to the app object, I have. : `app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();`  can you tell me what i need to add other than these lines?

Comment: No, It seems your configuration correct and if you register these two `app.UseAuthentication();`  and `app.UseAuthorization();`  service and still not working then its better to check log or debug manually.